# Using Mixpanel - Node Library in Express

Tags: node.js, express, backend, middleware, mixpanel

I am currently trying integrate the [Mixpanel Node library](https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-node) into a test application that I am building. This is a Node.js application using the [express framework](https://expressjs.com/).

As per the express docs, [I have a JS file to manage the project](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html), [a folder called "public" that contains all of my static files](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html), and another folder with the node modules that come with express.

I have two static HTML pages in "public" that I am trying to put mixpanel tracking into. I am running the project locally by running `node app.js`.

app.js includes:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const path = require('path');

//Mixpanel Additions
var Mixpanel = require('mixpanel');
var mixpanel = Mixpanel.init('<I am putting my project token here>', {
    protocol: 'https'
});

//App Configuration and Init
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/page.html'));
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

In my HTML files I try to use mixpanel functions by putting them into script tags:

```
<script>
mixpanel.track("event")
</script>
```

But when I run `node app.js` and view the page in my browser it says:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: mixpanel is not defined
```

I have a pretty poor understanding of node.js, but I am imagining that I need to use `app.use()`, `app.get()`, or something along those lines to get the Mixpanel lib loaded into the app. What am I doing wrong? I also realize that my understanding of Express and Node is pretty rudimentary, so any additional knowledge is appreciated, especially if I am way off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call mixpanel tracking functions in the browser, you should load the mixpanel library in a script tag on the browser side, as seen here:

https://developer.mixpanel.com/docs/javascript

The purpose of the node.js package is to send events from the server side, like if you wanted to log when page.html is rendered, you could do

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/page.html'));
    mixpanel.track('event')
});
```

Comment: This can only track the counts which is not that useful. How to link the event with specific users so that it can be linked with other events, retention etc?